# groupby and only keep rows if the value from a column appears on a different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have exchange data. A transaction initiator sends USD and will receive Euro in return. I want to make sure that each transaction contains the correct information about the initiator. The way to ensure that is that the one who is sending money to the exchange always appear in `to` as well within the same transaction.

```
transaction  from      to      currency
1             A    exchange      USD
1          exchange    A         Euro
1             B        C         Euro
2             C    exchange      USD
2             B        D         Euro
2             A        G         Euro
3             F    exchange      USD
3             D        A         Euro
3             B        F         Euro
4             R    exchange      USD
4             A        D         Euro
4             B        Q         Euro
```

I want to filter out the meaningful rows of transactions.

Desired df

```
transaction  from      to      currency
1             A    exchange      USD
1          exchange    A         Euro
3             F    exchange      USD
3             B        F         Euro
```

Here, for each transaction, the initiator is `A`, `C`, `F`, and `R`. But for `C`, `R`, there is no record of incoming transactions. So I want to exclude these transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.merge()` to find matching pairs.

```
pairs = df.reset_index().merge(
   df.reset_index(),
   left_on=["transaction", "from"],
   right_on=["transaction", "to"],
)
```

```
   index_x  transaction    from_x      to_x currency_x  index_y    from_y      to_y currency_y
0        0            1         A  exchange        USD        1  exchange         A       Euro
1        1            1  exchange         A       Euro        0         A  exchange        USD
2        6            3         F  exchange        USD        8         B         F       Euro
```

You can check/filter the currency columns if needed.

You can use the index columns to access the original rows:

```
>>> df.loc[pairs["index_x"].append(pairs["index_y"])].drop_duplicates()
   transaction      from        to currency
0            1         A  exchange      USD
1            1  exchange         A     Euro
6            3         F  exchange      USD
8            3         B         F     Euro
```